# In Access, I have an unbound text box to display multiple notes with date and author for the record. It doesn't update for new records

Tags: ms-access

I have an unbound listbox that displays notes by date and author for records in my table in my form based on the key for the displayed record. But when I move to the next record, the listbox doesn't update for the new record.

For the listbox properties, control source is blank. Row source is my query "sqlNotes" and my row source type is Table/Query. For my query, I read the ID for the record from my form and query my notes table to find all the notes for that ID. The listbox is supposed to display the date, author and note.

I have gone through the listbox wizard a few times trying different options, but it never updates with the results from the sql query. I have tested "sqlNotes" and it does work as it should.

```
sqlNotes
SELECT tblNotes.note_date AS Entry, tblNotes.author AS Author, tblNotes.note_text AS Comment, tblNotes.percent AS [%]
FROM tblNotes
WHERE (((tblNotes.note_id)=[Forms]![frmTasks]![ID]))
ORDER BY tblNotes.note_date;
```

Comment: You must requery the listbox in the OnCurrent event of the form.

Comment: What @Gustav said: the unbound control won't ever update unless you cause it programmatically to do so. You have to decide when you want that to happen, what event, and it sounds like you need the onCurrent event for the form.

Comment: Advise not to use spaces nor punctuation/special characters in naming convention. Better would be Pct.

Answer (score 2):

In the form current event, I had to requery the list box.

```
Me.ListBox.Requery
```

Comment: Good work. Answering your own question is a great accomplishment. I have spent many hours researching and solving my own MS Access problems.